# How to use normal Parse functions in ParseFacebookUtils?

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, parse-platform, gradle

I imported ParseFacebookUtils in build.gradle file

```
compile 'com.parse:parsefacebookutils-v4-android:1.10.3@aar'
```

The official documentation says it includes the parse-android:1.12.0, but I couldn't figure out how to use normal Parse functions such as logging in without facebook and even create Parse Objects.

I tried importing both

```
compile 'com.parse:parsefacebookutils-v4-android:1.10.3@aar'
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.12.0'
```

It compiled successfully, but when I launched the app, it returns classNotFoundException

```
01-05 15:41:33.560 11530-11530/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.peter.georeminder, PID: 11530
   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/facebook/FacebookSdk;
       at com.parse.FacebookController$FacebookSdkDelegateImpl.initialize(FacebookController.java:187)
       at com.parse.FacebookController.initialize(FacebookController.java:70)
       at com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(ParseFacebookUtils.java:108)
       at com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(ParseFacebookUtils.java:92)
       at com.peter.georeminder.utils.GeoReminderApplication.onCreate(GeoReminderApplication.java:34)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1013)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4707)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.facebook.FacebookSdk" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.peter.georeminder-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.peter.georeminder-2/lib/x86, /data/app/com.peter.georeminder-2/base.apk!/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
       at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
       at com.parse.FacebookController$FacebookSdkDelegateImpl.initialize(FacebookController.java:187) 
       at com.parse.FacebookController.initialize(FacebookController.java:70) 
       at com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(ParseFacebookUtils.java:108) 
       at com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(ParseFacebookUtils.java:92) 
       at com.peter.georeminder.utils.GeoReminderApplication.onCreate(GeoReminderApplication.java:34) 
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1013) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4707) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.facebook.FacebookSdk
       at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
       at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
       at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
            ... 16 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

**UPDATE:**
build.gradle file as below:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.peter.georeminder"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            pseudoLocalesEnabled true
        }
        debug {
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/AMap_Android_3DMapSDK_V3.1.1.jar')
    compile project(':searchbox')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1')
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'

    // I'm having problems with these three
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.12.0'
    compile 'com.parse:parsefacebookutils-v4-android:1.10.3@aar'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.8.2'


    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.2'
    compile 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk.android-process-button:library:1.0.4'
    compile 'com.github.recruit-lifestyle:WaveSwipeRefreshLayout:1.4'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.1.6@aar'
    compile 'com.ToxicBakery.viewpager.transforms:view-pager-transforms:1.2.32@aar'
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.11.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:4.6.3@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
}
```

When I run the app, the error message I got was:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: bolts/AggregateException.class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated into the [ParseFacebookUtil.java](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseFacebookUtils.html) class you also need to import the Facebook SDK V4.x.x.

Add this to build.gradle and try again:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
```

You will also need to initialize the Facebook SDK as stated into the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started).

**UPDATE**
Apparently 2 projects have the same class and it conflicts, try this:

```
compile('com.parse:parse-android:1.12.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.parse.bolts',
                module: 'bolts-android'
}
```

If this doesn't work try:

```
compile('com.parse:parse-android:1.12.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.parse.bolts',
                module: 'bolts-tasks'
}
```

Comment: I get 
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: bolts/AggregateException.class

Comment: Is it because I have both parse-facebook and parse sdks installed at the same time?

Comment: Also I still can't access the parse sdk inside the parse-facebook sdk.

Comment: Can you update your main question and iclude the entire build.gradle file? or atleast all the imports section